# Stripe cancel a pre-authorization

Tags: stripe-payments, stripe.net

I am using Stripe in a 2 part payment process. i.e.

1. Pre-authorize the card calling the Charge object with capture = false
2. Do some database work
3. Charge the card using charge capture

Do, or should I attempt to cancel this pre-authorization, using the refund method, if step 2 fails (i.e. the DB work)?

I am concerned that if I don't then customers will get irate if they see a charge appear on their account for a couple of days. i.e. before it expires naturally.

Comment: Its good practice to issue the refund

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you know for sure you will not capture the charge, it's definitely better to cancel the authorization (by [refunding](https://stripe.com/docs/api#create_refund) the uncaptured charge) rather than letting it run out. The sooner you cancel the authorization, the sooner the charge will disappear from your customers' credit card statements.

Answer (score 3):

From Stripe Documentation, there is no distinction between a VOID and REFUND, it's basically a reversal of the charge. A VOID would be issued if auth is not captured, that's my understanding.